# Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient allows me to create a user but does not allow me to change password

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a system comprised of an Angular SPA hosted in Azure and some Azure Functions for the APIs.  In an administrative app, I created an application that allows admin users to create new user accounts including specifying a password.  These new accounts are able to log into the line of business app that I created as well.  There is a requirement where we need to allow the same people who created the account to reset a password.  For some reason, the code that I wrote to set the password does not work.  It seems odd that a user can create an account, including setting the password, but for some reason the same user can't set the password independent of creating the user account.  FYI, there are no emails, these are user accounts, so giving the ability to request a password reset is not an option.

Here is the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Access to change password operation is denied.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-01-19T21:58:35",
      "request-id": "a1bc5b50-83e9-47ae-97c7-bda4f524fa0e",
      "client-request-id": "a1bc5b50-83e9-47ae-97c7-bda4f524fa0e"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
//this is the method that works
public async Task<Microsoft.Graph.User> CreateUserAsync(string givenName,
    string surname, string displayName, string userPrincipalName, string issuer, 
    string signInType, string initialPassword, GraphServiceClient graphClient) 
{
    var user = new Microsoft.Graph.User {
        AccountEnabled = true,
        GivenName = givenName,
        Surname = surname,
        DisplayName = displayName,
        Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>() {
            new ObjectIdentity {
                Issuer = issuer, 
                IssuerAssignedId = userPrincipalName,
                SignInType = signInType
            }
        },
        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile {
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
            Password = initialPassword
        }
    };

    return await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(user);
}

//This one does not work, returns: Access to change password operation is denied.
public async Task<Microsoft.Graph.User> SetPasswordAsync(
string userName, string currentPassword, string newPassword, GraphServiceClient graphClient) 
{
    await graphClient.Users[userName].ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword).Request().PostAsync();

    return something here;
}
```

Comment: May be this can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/9942/do-we-have-any-microsoft-graph-api-to-change-the-p.html

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a permission issue here. The function:`graphClient.Users[].ChangePassword()`is based on [reset password rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/passwordauthenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0),as the official doc indicated, only delegated permission works here and permission :`UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All` is needed.
After I granted this permission to my app:
[image]

it works perfectly for me:
[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.